# Add parameters to URL (resource from path, WKWebView)

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am using Swift 4 & `WKWebView`. The HTML pages are included in the app (not downloaded from server).
For configuration purpose I would like to add parameters to the URL (e.g. `...index.html?debug=true`).

Currently I am using the following approach to load the page:

```
let indexHTMLPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "f7Shoma/index", ofType: "html")
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: indexHTMLPath!)
let request = URLRequest(url: url)
...
appWebView!.load(request)
```

How can parameters be added/passed to the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `URLComponents` to create a URL with a query component:

```
var components = URLComponents(string: indexHTMLPath)
components?.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "debug", value: "true")]
if let result = components?.url {
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    appWebView!.load(request)
}
```